# Publish a jar file to GitLab package repository

Tags: scala, maven, jar, gitlab

I have a `scala` project, and using `SBT` I was able to generate a `jar` file out of it.

My next challenge is to to publish the generated jar file into Gitlab's package repository so I can reference this jar file (module) in another `scala` project.
I found several resources for that, using MAVEN or SBT .. but not sure how do I start, because I'm new to it and I'm a bit lost. Is it possible to publish the file using `SBT` as well?

[Reference 1](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/index.html): I'm lost in between GRADLE and MAVEN

[Reference 2](https://medium.com/credera-engineering/deploying-jar-files-to-gitlab-using-the-maven-release-plugin-via-ci-cd-d17c64c2ea3): I'm lost with this, because It's not clear to me how to achieve it and what is the relation in between the maven repository and the jar file.

Any simple guidance/clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the SBT way of publishing: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html

And then adapt the "repository URL" to be the one of your Gitlab. And follow Gitlab documentation of any specific configuration must be defined.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab now (since ~ 2023) supports sbt push/pull natively, see: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/408479

```scala
object Registry {
  val credentials: Credentials = sys.env
    .get("CI_JOB_TOKEN") // automatically generated token in the gitlab-ci
    .map(Credentials("GitLab Packages Registry", "gitlab.com", "gitlab-ci-token", _))
    .getOrElse(Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")) // for local development

  val additionalResolvers: Seq[MavenRepository] = Seq(
    "GitLab" at
      "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/maven"
  )

  def publishToGitlab(projectId: Int): Option[MavenRepository] =
    Some("gitlab" at s"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$projectId/packages/maven")
}
```

`build.sbt`:

```scala
ThisBuild / resolvers ++= Registry.additionalResolvers
ThisBuild / credentials += Registry.credentials
ThisBuild / publishTo := Registry.publishToGitlab(37794088) // Gitlab project id
```

`.sbt/.credentials`:

```
realm=GitLab Packages Registry
host=gitlab.com
user=Private-Token
password=<YOUR-TOKEN>
```